# Deploy Report Project by Windows Application

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a solution file that contains 10 report projects. I publish these projects manually with every change. I want to know that is there a solution to deploy these projects on report server programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rs` command.  You can make a reporting service script and then run it by using the `rs` command.